# Unix environment running C programs

Tags: c, unix

I am programming C programs in a Unix environment. I need to take a number from a user before the program is executed like so:

`./program.out 60`

How do I store the integer value in the C program?

Comment: using `argv`, read about command line arguments.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction (pun intended). I see what I need to do now.

Comment: Read about command line arguments of C programs at http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `argv[]` to get command line parameters, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n;

    if (argc != 2)      // check that we have been passed the correct
    {                   // number of parameters
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: command param\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    n = atoi(argv[1]);  // convert first parameter to int

    // ...              // do whatever you need to with `n`

    return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int main (int argc, char *argv [ ])
{
   //your code

}
```

`argv [1]` will then have the address of the numeric string which contains the number.

Then you can change this to an `int` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple to do and I hope I have got your question right. See below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  printf("Number of arguments is: %d\n", argc);
  printf("The entered value is %s\n", argv[1]);

  return 0;
}
```

And then compile it on Linux as:

```
gcc file.c
./a.out 32
```

The program should print the value you require.

Hope this helps.